# Two same flags (duplicate of)

Tags: support, flags, flag-dialog

Why there are two "duplicate of" flags:

- one is "it is a duplicate"
- another "duplicate of..." is in "it should be closed for another reason..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the "breadcrumbs" at the top, you'll see the top-level "it is a duplicate..." is just a short cut to the same dialogue.

> Flagging > Closing > Duplicate